# Multiple jQuery functions based on div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation function that has two parts, the first function don't work but the 2nd does.

https://jsfiddle.net/f7Lnthm1/

if you scroll down you will see the navigation fade in on scroll.. what i am trying to accomplish is have the same links show with no background color, and then when you scroll down the links scroll up with the web site then the same links fade in with the black navbar.

```
<div id="menu" style="display: block;">Top Bar</div>
<header id="header-active">
    <ul>
        <li>Nav links</li>
    </ul>
</header>
<div id="hero"></div>
<div style="height: 600px;">section 1</div>
```

> Jquery

```
(function($) {          
    $(document).ready(function(){                    
        $(window).scroll(function(){                          
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
                $('#header-active').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('#header-active').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/f7Lnthm1/3/

Basically, I split up the `CSS` for `#header` and the active version of it. You can use CSS for the animations (better to do this than JQuery anyway.

CSS:

```
#header {
  width:100%; 
  height:75px; 
  color: #000;
  z-index:9999;
  background: none;
}

#header.active {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  background:#000;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}
```

Then in the JS:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $('#header').addClass('active');
} else {
    $('#header').removeClass('active');
}
```

That obviously pushes the aqua box down, if you want it just to match, setting the background color of `#header` to `background: aqua` instead of `none` like I've done would work: https://jsfiddle.net/f7Lnthm1/6/ I also removed the `margin-top` from the `ul` inside `#header` so the aqua butts up against the red.

If you want it to sit on top of the aqua box, then you would want to set the position of `#header` to `absolute`: https://jsfiddle.net/f7Lnthm1/5/

Comment: that was exactly what i was trying to accomplish.. the only issue is it looks like it pushes the green box down..

Comment: @Codi I've edited that to explain and added links to two more js fiddles for you to look at :).

Comment: thanks so much Maverick.. this had me stumped all day.

Comment: If you use the `position: absolute` variation, you'll have to split the properties up further to get the fade-out. That's because the switch from fixed to absolute positioning isn't animated, it happens instantly. Otherwise, simply make sure you set the transition to start and stop at the exact right height and it'll work fine.